# AzureDevOps Duplicate dist folder in pipelines build ? Why?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

There is a duplication of a dist folder in the artifacts produced by the AzureDevOps -> Pipelines, the duplication is the /dist folder and also /drop/dist folder. EDIT: Full azure-pipeline.yml file

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

# Major modification referencing
# https://dev.to/thisdotmedia/continuously-integrating-angular-with-azure-devops-2k9l

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

# Build angular app area
- script: npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: npx ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm build'

# Testing area
- script: npm install puppeteer --save-dev
  displayName: 'Installing puppeteer (Headless browser for testing)'

- script: npx ng test --watch=false --codeCoverage=true
  displayName: 'Running Tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'

# Publishing items
#   deploy.psl (Powershell script to deploy)
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'deploy.ps1'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

#   Firebase.json
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1    
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Firebase.json'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'firebase.json'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

#   App
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    ArtifactName: 'drop/dist'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'

#   Code Coverage Results
- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverage/ng-azure-devops/cobertura-coverage.xml'
  displayName: 'Publish Code Coverage Results'

- script: npx ng lint
  displayName: 'Code Analysis'
```

I've tried the using 'drop' as the ArtifactName, which will NOT produce a duplicate folder artifact anywhere. I am very confused on why 'drop/dist' will produce another '/dist' artifact

[image: Image showing duplication of the dist folder]

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue on my side, would you please share more info about this issue, like, the build log, or a sample to reproduce this issue?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7fQyTKJq Logs here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AzureDevOps Duplicate dist folder in pipelines build ? Why?

I could reproduce this issue on my side.

When we use the publish the artifacts `dist` folder with `ArtifactName: drop/dist`, Azure Devops will **create a new folder `drop` first**, then publish the artifacts `dist` folder to that folder `drop`.

You can get this message from the build log:

> Upload '/home/vsts/work/1/s/dist' to file container:
>   '#/3620698/drop/dist'

However, the `drop` folder is already present by default. When we publish the `dist` folder with with `ArtifactName: drop/dist`, there are two `drop` folder, then Azure devops will publish `dist` folder to those two `drop` folders:

[image]

In order to understand this problem more clearly, you could **disable** the **Multi-stage pipelines** in the **Preview features**, then you will get the output:

[image]

**Obviously**, there are two `drop` folders here, that is the reason why you get the Duplicate dist folder in pipelines build.

So, to resolve this issue, we could change the `ArtifactName: drop/dist` to `ArtifactName: dropTest/dist`:

[image]

Now, the duplicate dist folder disappears.

Hope this helps.